# How to fill an open mesh which has multiple vertices

Tags: modeling

I want to fill in a mesh object of an open boat/canoe which has multiple vertices (26+) around the top of the object. What is the correct and/or easiest way to do this? In tried selecting every vertice on the top of the canoe one by one and then pressing F (fill) but it only filled in part of the area I want to fill (see image).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After much searching on Youtube I found a method to achieve what I wanted to do.
Select All
Edit mode
Edge select
Hold down ALT + SHIFT keys and left mouse click on one of the edges surrounding the 'open' area of the mesh object. This results in all the adjoining edges being selected.
Do the same for other edges around the area required until all edges are selected - I had to do this a total of 4 times for the canoe.
Press F to Fill.
[image]